# IdentityServer 4 with EntityFramework - Getting client properties?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I'm using Identity Server 4 with EntityFramework for configuration. I now want to get the current client from the login-page. I was able to get the client ID from the return url parameter. And then I'm using ConfigurationDbContext to get the client from the database.

But on the client, the Properties property is always null, even if I add a property on that client in the database.

How do i get hold of the properties for a client?

Comment: Dear user, it would be nice if you place some exerpt of your code to illustrate your problem. It will increase the probability of answer to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `ConfigurationDbContext` directly, there's a handy interface in the IdentityServer project that's more abstract: namely [`IClientStore`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4/Stores/IClientStore.cs). This interface itself contains a single function: [`FindClientByIdAsync`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4/Stores/IClientStore.cs), which can be used for obtaining a [`Client`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4/Models/Client.cs). `Client` includes a number of properties, including:

- ClientName
- LogoUri
- Properties

You can get an instance of `IClientStore` using DI (I expect you're already doing this for `ConfigurationDbContext`). Once you have this, just call `FindClientByIdAsync` accordingly:

```cs
var yourClient = await clientStore.FindClientByIdAsync(clientId);
```

When using this approach, `Properties` will be populated, as expected.

---

In order to explain why your original approach isn't giving the expected results, we need to understand how Entity Framework Core handles [loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/related-data). Simply put, when retrieving a [`Client`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/Entities/Client.cs) entity (this a *different* `Client` class to that I've used above), the *navigation properties* (e.g. `Properties`) are not populated by default, which is why you see `null`. I strongly recommend that you read the [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/ef/core/querying/related-data) docs if you're more interested in how this works.

The Entity Framework Core implementation of `IClientStore` ([`ClientStore`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4.EntityFramework/Stores/ClientStore.cs#L45)) handles this loading of related data for you. Here's a code snippet from the source itself:

```cs
public Task<Client> FindClientByIdAsync(string clientId)
{
    var client = _context.Clients
        // ...
        .Include(x => x.Properties)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClientId == clientId);

    var model = client?.ToModel();

    return Task.FromResult(model);
}
```

The `Include(x => x.Properties)` is what takes care of fetching the `Properties` from the database.